# How to extend an existing straight line in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an existing line initiated

```js
// material
const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });
// array of vertices
vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 5));
// 
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(vertices);
const line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
```

And what I want to do is extend this line following its initiation. I've read [this page on how to update things](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-update-things) and I don't think it fits this situation because instead of adding vertices to my shape, I want to move them. Then again, it's very likely I misunderstood. I've tried deleting the line and then redrawing it longer, but I can't get it to work without my browser crashing.

Comment: Is it always going to start at 0? Since the line starts at `0,0,0` you can just scale it with `line.scale.set(2,2,2)`

Comment: No, it won't always start at (0, 0, 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BufferGeometry` exposes its vertices through its `positions` [`BufferAttribute`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=vector3#api/en/core/BufferAttribute).  To change the positions, you should do something like the following:

```
//
// Assuming we want to move your line segment (0, 0, 0)-(0, 0, 5) by
// one unit in the direction of positive x, to (1, 0, 0)-(1, 0, 5).
//
// Get a reference to the "position" buffer attribute
const pos = geometry.getAttribute("position");
// Set the new positions
pos.setXYZ(0, vertices[0].x + 1, vertices[0].y, vertices[0].z);
pos.setXYZ(1, vertices[1].x + 1, vertices[1].y, vertices[1].z);
// Update the vertex buffer in graphics memory
pos.needsUpdate = true;
// Update the bounds to support, e.g., frustum culling
geometry.computeBoundingBox();
geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
```

Other methods exist, such as modifying the attribute's backing array directly and copying in a new array, but the general process will be the same.